# The witcher 3 alternative looks

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt on PS4 with two pieces of DLC. Now I saw a DLC´s with new alternative looks, then I download them and when I looked to downloads, there was my download alternative look but under it was: "waiting for installation"

When I press the X button there is an option start which then informs me: can´t find application, try look to store...

I've tried to move the game to expanded storage, tried to download DLC when ID was in P, when CD wasn't in the PS4 drive and I don't know what to do or how successful install this DLC

Comment: Do you have enough space on your disk to download the dlc?

Comment: Yes..i have over 300 GB free space

Comment: Have you tried to remove the dlc and download it again?

Comment: yes, many times

Answer (score 1):

It is a small chance , but did you download it from a different store originally? I actually originally downloaded the base game from the UK store , Now I live in North America , had to go back into the UK Store in order to install the DLC etc..